# Circular Progress Bar Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to create a segmented circular progress bar to behave like a count down timer, such that each segment has its own time limit.

There is one iOS app pTimer+ and I want to make similar countdown timer in Android.

[image: pTimer+]
<sub>(source: [jiaojianli.com](http://www.jiaojianli.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Pre1.jpg))</sub>

So far I am able to achieve circular progress bar that behaves like countdown timer but has no concept of segments or blocks.

[image: Clock]

Answer (score 0):

use this link - [I need to design this "red" percentage circle dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119071/i-need-to-design-this-red-percentage-circle-dynamically/29119275#29119275)
in that you can change the color of the progress bar bases on the progress.

Hope it helps.

Edit: For Initializing the Progress bar with color segments you can try using the following code.

```
<gradient
android:angle="0"
android:centerX="50%"
android:centerColor="@color/green"
android:startColor="@color/orange"
android:endColor="@color/red"
android:type="linear"
/>
```

Comment: I want to initialize progress bar with multiple color segments.

Comment: @user3299028 see my edit . But it can only allow you to have 3 colors.

Comment: I cannot limit it to just 3 .. Segments are decided based on the dynamic data and mostly it would be greater than 4 or 5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this library can help. It has circular-segment progress bar and it is easily customizable library: [Android-progressviewslib](https://github.com/natasam/DemoProgressViewsLibApp)